# Can we ask idea of software?

Tags: discussion

I am new to Programmers Stack Exchange. I have read the faq. I have a basic question here that can I ask about the idea of developing software.

Just for sake of example, I have started a job in software house and my CEO hands me a project. And I have no idea or flow chart in my mind through which I would develop that application. For example client needs an E-diary. I have idea of `WPF` but lacking flow of app.

So my question is can I ask about the app that "what would be the idea to develop the application"?

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: Surely you have received more information than "build an e-diary"? (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: There are computers and they can do a useful stuff. So, by helping to exploit the computers, the programmers do the stuff the people need.

Comment: after i see the downvotes i feel i has put up a wrong question.

Comment: @jailedabroad You would be feeling right.

Comment: [What does voting mean here](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @Oded thanks for sharing the link. Before asking this question i read the this <a href="http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq">FAQ</a>. As this question is migrated from programmers to meta programmers so thats y u find question here.

Comment: @Oded i am really not concerned about the downvotes but i need to know if some of the community members have downvoted my question then they atleast should comment why they downvoted the question and could possibly point me to right direction. These comments will be helpfull for me in future when i ask a question.

Comment: Well, on programmers it was downvoted because it was off-topic there. Questions _about_ programmers should be asked on _meta.programmers_.

Comment: Well, we don't force anyone to do these things as it would reduce participation in the site (including moderation - downvotes are a very important part of that). I agree it would be _nice_ to get it explained, but not everyone has the time or inclination to do so.

Comment: ok thannks. Got you. Next time i`ll be watchfull

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what is expected of the system and what are the project resources before you begin. You should check if the company has a business analyst or system analyst who is usually tasked with front end analysis of requirements. If you end up being the one to do that,  get a person (or more) from the customer's side assigned to your project. This person should be able to answer questions about the project goals, objectives, business rules, processes, flow of steps in a process etc. You then need to establish basic requirements using the common requirements gathering techniques. Whether you end up usng WPF or another technology is not the matter at this stage. You should not begin work on something you don't understand about. You should ask the right people who are assigned by management to answer.

Comment: so that means i cant ask a question about implementation right?

Comment: I guess so...make sure the question is well defined.

Comment: @jailedabroad: No. You may ask a specific, constructive, and answerable question. But don't expect the Community to do your work for you.

Comment: @JimG.i know and i am not a school boy. I dont expect someone to do work for me.This question is about the idea and suggestion that can we ask such quesionsm i dont know what downvoters thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by gathering requirements. Entire books have been written on the subject.

[Agile development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development), [test driven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), Minimum Viable Product are some of the tricks of the trade. There are many more.

You are standing on the rocky precipice of the trade of software development. It's a long way down.

Good luck!

Comment: Link to Minumum Viable Product - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product (S.O. limited my links to 2 :sad_face:)